# AJAX request to rails is omitting closing curly braces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, vue.js, ruby-on-rails-5, axios

I have an [app hosted on heroku](http://recipes.jamesmklein.com) found at [this repo](https://github.com/kleinjm/recipe_viewer) (full source available).

When I perform a post or put request, the closing curly braces are missing. For example, the code found [here](https://github.com/kleinjm/recipe_viewer/blob/master/app/javascript/pages/recipes/form.vue#L380) performs a post to create a recipe.

```
this.axios.post('recipes', { recipe: resource });
```

I see the following raw request in the network tools.

```
{"recipe":{"ingredients":"","name":"t","tags":[],"categories":[]}}
```

But server side I'm seeing this error.

```
{"recipe":{"ingredients":"","name":"test","tags":[],"categories":[]

ActionDispatch::Http::Parameters::ParseError (765: unexpected token at '{"recipe":{"ingredients":"","name":"test","tags":[],"categories":[]'):

rails/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:117: in `rescue in parse_formatted_parameters'
rails/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:111:in `parse_formatted_parameters'
rails/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:381:in `block in POST'
```

It's as if the last two curly braces are cut off. I've gone all the way to jump into `ActionDispatch::Request` and pry

```
> get_header "RAW_POST_DATA"
=> "\r\n" + "{\"recipe\":{\"ingredients\":\"\",\"name\":\"t\",\"tags\":[],\"categories\":[]"
```

I can't tell if it's coming from the axios side or the rails side. Since the dev tools are showing a valid request, I'm assuming it's on the rails side but I have no idea what would cause this.

It works [on heroku](http://recipes.jamesmklein.com) but not in the development environment and I can't think of anything that has changed. To reproduce, you can setup like any other rails app and seed a user and try to create a recipe with a title.

Comment: Could it be that the request is not being processed as JSON? The parse error could be caused by rails  trying to parse it as form data.

Comment: Hmm could be possible. How would I check on the backend? I'm seeing this in the dev tools for the request.
`Accept: application/json`
`Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8`

Comment: It should be in the logs. Something like ”processing as json”

Comment: The default content type in axios is `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` [defaults](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/lib/defaults.js). You can check `request.format` in the controller to figure out which is being used.

Comment: I can't get a breakpoint into the controller action. I tried adding the following into `ApplicationController` but it breaks before getting through actionpack/the middleware. `rescue_from ActionDispatch::Http::Parameters::ParseError  { |e| binding.pry }`. Here is [the full stack trace and log](https://gist.github.com/kleinjm/64ee228da5bfba609f32e3c59779f50a)

Comment: [Here are the axios configs](https://github.com/kleinjm/recipe_viewer/blob/de2b746adf2082af92bedf0200b97234cc4c2495/app/javascript/packs/application.js#L67-L71)

Comment: Solved, I cleared my cookies on localhost. :shrug: :facepalm: